# Method that doesn't allow more participants than the maximum and same number of registration

Tags: java

I have a issue here. I need to create this method:

Method: `registraParticipante (Aluno alu)` that will receive by parameter one
student(`Aluno`) and add to the participant(`participante`) array. The method should also implement the following rules:

- control not to allow more participants to register which was defined in the attribute: Maximum number of participants(`qtMaxParticipantes`);
- not allow registration of a participant who has the same number of registration(`int matricula`) of an already registered participant.

I have the superclass `Usuario` (means User) with the int `matricula` in it
and the subclass `Aluno` (means student)

```
    PROBLEM SOLVED - Thanks Andre.

public void registraParticipante(Aluno alu) {

    if (!matriculaJaExistente(alu)) 
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i < listaDeParticipantes.length; i++) 
        {
            if (listaDeParticipantes[i] == null) 
            {
                listaDeParticipantes[i] = alu;
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Número maximo de participante atingido.");
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Aluno já matriculado.");
    }

}

    public boolean matriculaJaExistente(Aluno a)
    {
        boolean resultado = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < listaDeParticipantes.length; i++)
        {if (listaDeParticipantes[i].getMatricula() == a.getMatricula())
            {
                resultado = true;
            }
            else
            {
                resultado = false;
        }
    }
        return resultado ;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow.    You're going to be asked to explain what happens when you run your code, how it's not doing what you want.  You should also edit your post to remove the line numbers.

Comment: For quicker help, try to format your code properly. Your `verificaNovaMatricula` method always returns `false`, you might have a look at that. A good practice is to always use brackets `{}` for the `if else` blocks

Comment: Hi CPerkins, thanks! I will try it...
jhamon, i didn't get it. Why is it always returning false?

Comment: when i try method verificaNovaMatricula i get "int cannot be converted to Aluno". I added class Usuario and class Aluno here

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you necessarily have to use an array, so I guess that using a List would be the best solution, than, your code would look like this:

```
List<Aluno> alunosList = new ArrayList();
private int maxParticipantes = 5; // arbitrary number

public void registraParticipante(Aluno a) {
    if (alunosList.size() > maxParticipantes || alunoJaRegistrado(a)) {
        System.out.println("Can't add this aluno");
    } else {
        alunosList.add(a);
    }
}

public boolean alunoJaRegistrado(Aluno aluno) {
    boolean result;
    for (Aluno a : alunosList) { // this goes through each aluno on the list
        if (a.getMatricula() == aluno.getMatricula) {
            result = true;
            break;
        } else result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why did u name "a" and then "aluno" ? Can't it be the same?

Comment: If you mean on the for loop, the names have to be different because "a" means the current item being iterated in the list and "aluno" is the one passed as parameter and you are comparing both of them in search of the same "matricula" number.

Comment: Hi, idk yet how exactly i should make more questions(in the same question) in stackoverflow so i did edit your anwser. can u check it? thanks

Comment: Just added() after the getMatricula and it worked. But I still don't get the .add

Comment: The `add()` method is particular from List, arrays have no such type of method. Also, I guess this is getting too extensive and messy, if you'd like, you could leave a contact of yours and we'd resolve externally.